# semantic similarity in medical terms

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nltk, topic-modeling, text-processing

I want to find out the similar clinical terms in two list with abundant spelling errors. Now I am using SequenceMatcher to find it as most similar. Example:

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher
def similar(a, b):
    return round(SequenceMatcher(None, a, b).ratio()*100, 1)

print similar('hypertesnion','hypertension')          # 91.7
print similar('high blood pressure','hypertension')   # 19.4
```

In second case, similarity between 'high blood pressure' and 'hypertension' is very low but they are actually similar terms. Also note that there are variety of spellings present for both 'hypertension' and ' high blood pressure' in lists.

Is there any way to catch similarity in these clinical terms?

I suppose two things are required. Firstly, correct the spelling and then coding
   them to single term to calculate similarity.

Edit:
Or is there any way to create model using list of synonym to code them into single term, in case I have a list sample coding as follows:

```
'hypertension' 'hypertension'
'hypertesnio' 'hypertension'
'high blood pressure' 'hypertension'
'increased blood pressure' 'hypertension'
'raised blodd presure' 'hypertension'
```

Comment: You might take a look at https://www.nlm.nih.gov/research/umls/knowledge_sources/metathesaurus/index.html.

Comment: There's no easy way to do it in python or nltk unless you have some sort of dictionaryand UMLS as @BillBell suggested will be the best source to map different words to their semantic equivalent term. In addition you can also look at the https://bioportal.bioontology.org/

Comment: Thanks @BillBell . Suppose I have a list (example updated in question), How can I now use it to improvise similarity search.

Answer (score 2):

You should explore using word2vec and the similarity insights and relationships among words that using them brings. Most NLP libraries support word2vec and I found a model trained on medical data at: http://bio.nlplab.org/. There could be other word2vec models that can be used with libraries like Spacy, sklearn, etc. for similarity matching in the health care domain.

You will still need to address the spelling mistakes separately as you pointed out already

Answer (score 1):

Here is an admittedly flawed approach that takes a list of symptoms, as you might find them recorded in a clinical trial, and turns them into a list that might be acceptable according to some standards.

```
symptoms = [
    'hyprtension',
    'hi blood pressure',
    'high blod pressure',
    'increased blood pressure',
    'bad headache',
    'migraine',
    'migraine headache',
    'mygrain',
    ]

canonical_inverted_dictionary = {
    'high blood pressure': 'hypertension',
    'increased blood pressure': 'hypertension',
    'hypersion': 'hypertension',
    'migraine': 'migraine',
    }

from difflib import SequenceMatcher

def mapper(raw_term, threshold=0.7):
    best = 0
    for term in canonical_inverted_dictionary:
        ratio = SequenceMatcher(None, raw_term, canonical_inverted_dictionary[term]).ratio()
        if ratio > best:
            best = ratio
            best_item = term
    if best > threshold:
        return canonical_inverted_dictionary[best_item]

for symptom in symptoms:
    print (symptom, mapper(symptom))
```

The output is this:

```
hyprtension hypertension
hi blood pressure None
high blod pressure None
increased blood pressure None
bad headache None
migraine migraine
migraine headache None
mygrain migraine
```

Simply put, SequenceMatcher is not really up to the task of working with natural language. It cannot discern that 'hi blood pressure' is similar to 'high blood pressure.' However, this code does illustrate a principle. It is that, you can use code to 'recognise' phrases such as 'hi blood pressure' as 'high blood pressure,' and then convert these to some standard term such as 'hypertension' using an inverted dictionary.

I suspect that it might be possible to do this in many cases, in practice, by splitting incoming terms using a stemmer, then looking for legitimate substitutes for words and finally looking these up in the inverted dictionary.